# C# Highscore system for basic Game

Tags: c#

Hi I am making a high score system for my game.

Right now I am using the following code:

```
string currentScore = File.ReadLines("Highscores.txt").Take(4).First();

int.TryParse(currentScore, out currentscoreInt);

if (currentscoreInt < score)
{
    string writeScore = score.ToString();
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Highscores.txt");
    file.WriteLine("NAME:");
    file.WriteLine(name);
    file.WriteLine("SCORE:");
    file.WriteLine(writeScore);
    file.WriteLine("CHARACTER:");
    file.WriteLine(character);

    file.Close();
}
```

The Problem I am having is that it just re writes it ven if the score (Latest score) is smaller than the score read from the file. I believe it is because the string read from file and then converted to int is returning as 0. I am unsure as to what to do next. Thankyou

Comment: Check if it is `0`, put a breakpoint on the line and hover over the variable

Comment: `currentScore ` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Your question shows a significant lack of understanding of basic coding principles.  You have read the name instead of the score. You have named the old score "currentScore" and the new one just "score".  You have overwritten the entire high scores file with just one score.  Break your problem down into very simple tasks and figure out each one, one by one.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be the first line:

```
string currentScore = File.ReadLines("Highscores.txt").Take(4).First();
```

[Take(4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will take the first 4 lines of the file Highscores.txt, and [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will return the first element. Judging by your write code, this would take "NAME:" and parse it as an integer - which is probably not gonna do what you'd like it to do

Answer (score 1):

```
int.TryParse(currentScore, out currentscoreInt);
```

`TryParse` will return a boolean, telling you if the parse was successful or not.  IF it isn't, the `out` variable will be set to it's default value, hence `currentscoreInt` is 0.

Verify that your `TryParse` succeeded, and go from there:

```
bool parsed = int.TryParse(currentScore, out currentscoreInt);
if(parsed) 
{
   //.....
}
```

In all though your code is very confusing.  Why would `currentscore` be pulled from the highscores list?  You should debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

.Take(4) grabs the first 4 lines.  First() then grabs the first line (from the first four), which it looks like should be "NAME:", which does not convert to an int.  You probably want .Last() instead of .First().